# Create a cron job to delete old post

Tags: php, sql, joomla, cron

can i make a cron job to delete old post from sql?

i create this cron job But it does not delete the records

```
mysql DATABASE -e "DELETE FROM table_posts WHERE end_date < subdate(now(), interval 0 day)" >/dev/null
```

i try to use this code in SSH Command But it does not delete also -

```
mysql> DELETE * FROM [#aaa_table_posts] WHERE [end_date] <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAYS);
```

my time field look like this - 2013-06-23 23:59:00

Answer (score 1):

Both of your queries are outright broken with syntax errors:

command line version: there is no function `subdate` in MySQL. Perhaps you mean `date_sub()`?

mysql monitor: `DAYS` is an invalid interval. perhaps you mean `DAY`.

in the greater scheme of things, why a `INTERVAL 0 DAY` anyways?